# Nested and complicated select statement

Tags: c#, database, select, sql

What i want to do here is simple...display an ivestigators ID and him corresponding name...
That can be easily done from the users table by selecting based on the user type.
However i want to select only some type of investigators. The analogy here is investigators are assigned to an exhibit for them to investigate. One investigator can be assigned to a maximum of 3 cases only. Now during the assigning of investigators, i want to write a select statement that would retrieve only investigatorID's that have been assigned to less than or equal to 2 cases. I have included exhibit and users  table that shows sample data below.
[image]

[image]

Now i sort of have an idea that i will have to first of all pick out all the investigators by their ID from the users list and then filter them through the exhibit table by dropping those assigned to 3 cases and leaving just those with two cases. then afterwards i use this IDs to select the Investigators name.

the big questions is how do i write the statement??

Comment: why have you marked this with the C# tag? Are you searching for an SQL statement to do this, or something in C#, e.g. a LINQ statement?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing the foreign key relationship here, is it "OfficerID" or "InvestigatorID" that will be joining back to the users table?

Comment: InvestigatorID is the only one matching an entry in the bottom table. (IO123).

Comment: @Simon, you're right about that, I missed that one. And since he never mentions the word "officer", it's probably safe to conclude that's the relationship.  Chris's answer should do the trick then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT InvestigatorID From Cases GROUP BY (InvestigatorId) HAVING COUNT(INvestigatorId) < 3
```

Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Splendid....am sorry Steve if my question was ambiguous...and to AdamRalph am using the statement in a C# application which is why i tagged C# as well and to Simon..thanks for the clarification...and Chris..thanks for the answer....i havent tried it out yet though i i can see it does the job clean...